# iPad App Design : UITableView?

Tags: uitableview

I am building a iPad App with three screens. The first screen gathers some information from the user and is then displayed on the second screen.

I am using Storyboards with UIPopovers on the button.

[image]

This looks pretty ugly. I think it would look better if I could present the data like it is in Apple's Settings app:

[image]

I don't want the split view, just the part on the right hand pane, which I believe is a UITableView.

Could I get this same look without the UITable View. I really don't want any of that functionality, just the look? The reason I ask is I want the easiest way to do this.

Any other suggestions for the layout?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-hand pane is using a `UITableView` with the style set to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

**Example:**

> ```
> - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style;
> ```

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,300) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

See the [UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewStyle) for more information.